# VBA formula error

Tags: excel, vba, formula

When trying to run the following code, I get the error application or object-defined error.
Can anyone detect the error?
When I output the formula as a string, everything seems fine. When I try to use it in a formula however it does not work. I've been looking at it for hours and have tried anything I could come up with.

An example of the what is in the column createdColumn: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 10:28:13 +0100

```vb
    Dim createdColumn, updatedColumn, resolvedColumn As Integer

    createdColumn = GetColumnValueByName("created")
    updatedColumn = GetColumnValueByName("updated")
    resolvedColumn = GetColumnValueByName("resolved")

   Sheets("Current Data").Select
   ActiveSheet.Columns(createdColumn).Select
   Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   ActiveSheet.Cells(2, createdColumn + 1).Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=LEFT(RIGHT(R[0]C[-1],LEN(R[0]C[-1])-5), LEN(R[2]C[-1])-5-6)"


    Dim dateArr As Variant
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34)
    dateArr = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, createdColumn + 1).Value, " ")
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, createdColumn + 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=DATE(" & dateArr(0) & ";MONTH(DATEVALUE(" &_ 
        dateArr(1) & "&" & tmp & "));" & dateArr(2) & ") + " & dateArr(3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you defined 'createdColumn' and please show an example of what you are trying to 'Split' .. is it 11 26 2014 or what?

Comment: What the value in ActiveSheet.Cells(2, createdColumn + 1)?

Comment: Sorry, I knew I had to extend the information provided but I had the full code on my other laptop. Anyways, here it is. If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: What I'm doing is: in the created column there is a particular data format. I create two new columns. The first column after the created column is a calculation which basically just removes the comma and the abbreviation of the day. In the second column I want the format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: @pnuts: I'm using MONTH(DATEVALUE()) to transform the abbreviation of the month (e.g. Sep) to the number that represents the month (9). So MONTH(DATEVALUE("Sep" & "1")) = 9

Comment: What line is the code highlighting when it errors?

Comment: @Chrismas007: The last one. There is an error in the last formula

Comment: When you use the syntax `dateArr(#)`, I believe it is trying to run a function of those numbers.  But since `dateArr` is defined as a `variant`, it realizes it isn't a function and returns error?  What is the purpose of the numbers in the `dateArr`?

Comment: Nevermind, found the syntax for Split...  See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax I found when using a Split:

```
Dim dateArr() As String
dateArr() = Split(blah)
```

then if you need to convert string to date you might have to use
`cdate(dateArr(#))`

Comment: Thanks. I can indeed use cDate in a for loop to change the dates. I didn't know this existed in vba. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, this is closer to the solution I want. However, I have another issue: Oct is not recognized as my default language is Dutch. Is there something that is not language dependent? I want it to work on every computer regardless of the language.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to reformat the date, there is a rather simple method. You can use something like this, which avoids your needing to do the Split:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Format(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, createdColumn + 1).value, "d/m/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Or to correct the syntax in what you were trying, you would use this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = dateArr(0) & "/" & Month(DateValue("01 " & dateArr(1) & " 2014")) & "/" & dateArr(2) & " " & dateArr(3)
```

Comment: Hi, you have indeed resolved the issue. However, I have another issue: Oct is not recognized as my default language is Dutch. Is there something that is not language dependent? I want it to work on every computer regardless of the language.

Comment: I'm too lazy to switch my default language to test this, but I guess you are saying neither of these options work for you? I guess your cell doesn't have "Jan Feb Mar... etc."?  Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907765/excel-datevalue-function-independent-of-international-settings and if one of the suggestions there can't be adapted, I can develop some code.